# c# numerator denominator on treeview

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, treeview, nodes

My data structure is like this.

```
public class Node{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public bool IsAlive { get; set;}
   public string Dividend { get; set;}
   public Node Parent { get; set;}
}
```

I want to divide pie between alive shareholder, and I want to show pieces as numerator denominator on tree view.

[image]

But actually my numerator and denominator should be like this.

[image]

But I could not calculate the numerator and denomirator title values.

```
IList<Node> shareholders = new List<Node>{
    new Node { Parent = null, Name ="A", IsAlive = false, Dividend = "" },
    new Node { Parent = A,    Name ="B", IsAlive = false, Dividend = "" },
    new Node { Parent = A,    Name ="C", IsAlive = true,  Dividend = "" },
    new Node { Parent = B,    Name ="D", IsAlive = true,  Dividend = "" },
    new Node { Parent = B,    Name ="E", IsAlive = true,  Dividend = "" }
}
```

Comment: Is the tree always binary, and can alive nodes also have children?

Comment: One node may have many child nodes.